# Is there a detailed plot summary for The Fifth Season?

Tags: online-resources, broken-earth, fifth-season

I just started reading *The Obelisk Gate*, book two of the *Broken Earth* trilogy by N. K . Jemison and am lost. I've forgotten a lot of what happened in book one, *The Fifth Season*. Usually I go to Wikipedia but the book's article has no plot information. A Google search turns up only reviews. **Where can I find a detailed plot summary of *The Fifth Season*?**

Comment: This is probably the easiest question to google.

Comment: Edited to mention that I *have* Googled and only reviews come up.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://strangehorizons.com/non-fiction/reviews/the-fifth-season-by-n-k-jemisin/)

Comment: I've reversed my vote after trying to find things, it's surprisingly difficult.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this one: http://thebooksmugglers.com/2015/08/joint-review-the-fifth-season-by-n-k-jemisin.html

I found it sufficient. Hope it helps, if it’s still necessary

Comment: If you could include a quote to show us why this would be a good option, that would make your answer a lot better.